# Highlight cell values starting with the same 'n' chars

Tags: excel, vba

I need to highlight(in a column) all cell values starting with the same 'n' chars. So I find a 'highlight duplicates' code and I inserted left function on activecell:

```
    For Each CL In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Left(CL.Value, 4)) > 1 Then
    CL.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    Next CL
```

but doesn't work because incompatibility of left and countif. A solution is to insert a new column which calculates the first n chars, then apply the original loop on it.
But I wonder if exists a much more elegant idea :)  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want? The * is a wild card.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Left(CL.Value, 4) & "*") > 1 Then
```

Comment: it's working. thank you! which is the difference between 'with *' and 'without *' ?

Comment: See eg here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34The asterisk represents any character so Frederick would count if you were looking for Fred. Does that help?

Comment: quote "LEFT applied to a multi-cell range returns an array. The surrounding function must be capable of processing such arrays. SumProduct does, CountIf doesn't." so the '*' makes countif to work? ok :)